# How can I find out with which software a web page was written?

Tags: firefox, website, web-development

I'd like to know which software was used for the development of the web page http://www.daraz.pk and http://www.jabong.com . How can I do it? Is there any tool for Firefox that could help me finding out this information?

Comment: Is there any specific reason you made an exact duplicate of the existing question?

Answer (score 2):

Google Chrome has a plugin called [Chrome Sniffer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-sniffer/homgcnaoacgigpkkljjjekpignblkeae), you can use this to determine most if not all of the used JavaScript libraries and web frameworks. Unfortunately I do not know any equivalent of it in Firefox.

Comment: Easy enough to install another browser though +1

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome, Firefox or Internet Explorer 9 you can use F12 to view the code (Firefox is a plugin you must install called Firebug).

Unless the software comments out where it came from though, I don't believe you can tell what software made the page. Or do you just want to know the underlying technologies?

Comment: You don't need Firebug. In fact, the majority of the tools Firebug offers have been integrated for a while now. It's accessible through the Web Developer menu, and the main toolbar can be opened with `Shift` + `F2`. Or you could right click on any page and click `View Page Source`, which applies for all aforementioned browsers.

Comment: Or use `control`-`u` to view the page source with needed a mouse. That works in every graphical browser I ever used, except for IE.